# iOS continuous fade-out and fade-in animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

In `objective-c`, I want to add fade in and fade out animation to a `UIView`.  I want to do the fade-out and fade-in animation continuously.  To illustrate it, what effect I want to have is as following:

fade out - fade in - fade out - fade in - ...

What I'm trying is as following:

```
-(void)fadeOutIn:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    static CGFloat alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat| UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         alpha = abs((int)(alpha - 1.0));
                         view.alpha = alpha;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
```

I also tried following:

```
-(void)fadeOutIn:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat| UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              view.alpha = 1.0;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

But the issue is they worked all the same, i.e., the `UIView` will fade out properly and **SUDDENLY** show up(not fade in), then fade out again...

Seems the fade in animation not work at all.  Does anybody know what's wrong of my code please?  Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    self.customIV.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Comment: and in fact, THIS answer is the safer answer, just so you know, this one its less dangerous than recursing the method

Comment: Just want to add that, if you wish to make the button clickable. You can add a flag uiviewanimationoptionallowuserinteraction and change self.customIV.alpha = 0.1

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat| UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                               view.alpha = 0.0;
                             }
                 completion:nil];
```

Just call this once

Comment: Hi @Anc Ainu, thank you for your quick reply.  Can you be more specific please?  I tried your suggestion, but not work, please note that I tried like this: 'options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState'

Comment: I edited my answer after reading better your question (and other answers).
It's same as Joey, but without the singleton which would result in a problem if you use the function twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's this, Vigor, this does work, but I had to modify the code, this is somewhat dangerous code, due to it's constant recursiion, but you'll get the point:

```
-(void)fadeOutIn
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0.0
                        options:  UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [[self contentView] emailField].alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              [[self contentView] emailField].alpha = 1.0;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              [self fadeOutIn];

                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

I would really rethink how this works, I used it on a button in my view and it will recurse constanly, until the view is removed from the superview. I had to hardcode the button in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
YourView.alpha = 1;// set the initial value of alpha

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                         animations:^{
                                YourView.alpha = 0; // set the max value of alpha
                            } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for Swift 3,4 and 5

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat.rawValue), UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.RawValue(UIView.AnimationCurve.easeInOut.rawValue)), UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse.rawValue)] , animations: {
        self.logoCenterImageView.alpha = 0
    }) { finished in
    }
```